# Number of different scenarios that a finalist basketball team can be declared NBA champion

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The A and B basketball teams made it to the NBA Finals, where the team that would arrive first was to be declared champion in 4 wins, in a series of consecutive (minimum 4, and maximum 7) matches. Finally, we learn on the news that team A has been declared champion, without knowing exactly how this happened. For example, the order of finals only took 4 games because team A "swept" team B making from the beginning of the series 4 consecutive victories. But the series is not ruled out also ended 4-2 in favor of A, with B winning the first and fifth match and team A to win their second, third, fourth, and sixth matches series. Count the number of different scenarios (ie, sequences results for consecutive matches, until the first time team A arrived the 4 wins, while B had a maximum of 3 wins) which could lead to the declaration of A as the champion team of the NBA. It is recalled that in basketball each match results in a victory for one of the two teams (i.e., there are no ties).

So far I started with the cases for group B wins (0,1,2,3 wins). In any case, I thought about what a sequence of results would look like. E.g., I will have a sequence that looks like B, B, A, A, A, A or A, A, B, A, B. I tried to generalize this sequence (e.g., with possible spaces between "A"). But I did not succeed, can you help me find the permutations?

Comment: Binomial coefficients and break into cases based on how many games total are played noting that the final game must go to the overall winner and exactly three of the non-final games must go to the overall winner.

Comment: A wins the last match, so this last match can be exclude from the analyze. Rest 3 wins for A, and $n$ wins for B ($n \le 3$) ;  So the answer is $\sum _{n=0,1,2,3} {C(n+3,3)}=1+4+10+20=35$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question is not clear to me. I present a general method that works in different cases. You can pick the right one.

**First case:** The number of sequences that include 4 $A$s and maximum 3 $B$s

There are five spaces around four $A$s, that is, $- A - A - A -A -$

Define $x_i$ as the number of $B$s in the $i$th place, $i=1,\dots,5$.

We need to count non-negative solutions that satisfy the following inequality:

$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 \le 3,$$

which is equal to the number of non-negative solutions to the following equation:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+y=3. $$

The latter can be easily computed as:

$$ \binom{3+6-1}{6-1}. $$

**Second case:** The number of sequences that include 4 $A$s and 3 $B$s

We need to count non-negative solutions to the following equality:

$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 =3,$$

which is

$$ \binom{3+5-1}{5-1}. $$

**Third case:** The number of sequences ending in $A$ that include 4 $A$s and maximum 3 $B$s.

In this case, the last space considered in the first case cannot be considered ($x_5=0$), and there are four spaces around four $A$s: $- A - A - A -A$.

The answer is the number of non-negative solutions that satisfy the following inequality:

$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \le 3,$$

given by

$$ \binom{3+5-1}{5-1}. $$

The answers of the second and third cases are the same because each sequence ending in $A$ (in the 3rd case) is related to only one sequence with length 7 (in the 2nd case) obtained by adding the remaining $B$s after the last $A$, e.g., $ABAAA \Leftrightarrow ABAAA+BB $ .

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to care about is that of the seven games originally allowed for, team A won four. That can happen in $7 \choose 4$ ways.

For any choice of those four games, say that team A’s series-clinching fourth win happened in game $i$. Then any games less than $i$ that were not among their four wins must have been won instead by team B. And any games at all that are greater than $i$ simply got canceled.

So the number of different ways team A can take the best-of-seven series is simply $7 \choose 4$.